# Push-уведомления на сайте для всех пользователей

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, push-уведомления

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать на сайте (html, php, js) вывод Push уведомлений.

Покопавшись нашел "решение" как выводить такие уведомления через HTML5 Notification, но такие уведомления выводятся только после "нажатия на кнопку" самим пользователем!

Задача состоит в следующем: я добавляю на сайт новость/статью/... и "тут же", у всех согласившихся получать уведомления, всплывает сообщение типа "добавлена новость...".

Вот как это реализовать?

P.S. Сейчас интересует отправка уведомлений в браузеры компьютеров. Если будет возможность получать такие уведомления еще и на телефонах - это будет великолепным плюсом.

Comment: это делается через сервер.

Comment: `HTML5 Notification, но такие уведомления выводятся только после "нажатия на кнопку" самим пользователем!` - неправда. такие уведомления показываются если пользователь находится непосредственно на сайте. но нотификацию рассылает сам сайт (через js API)